# Using an infinitive as a subject

Tags: infinitive

In my native language, Spanish, it is possible to use a phrase introduced by an infinitive as a subject. If i'm not wrong, it is plausible in English too. For example:

*Living in the countryside is relaxing.*

But, can this be done in German? I know that if use a noun the sentence will have the same meaning, but I would like to know this fact.

Is one of these possibilities right?

*Wohnen auf dem Land, ist entspannend.*

*Auf dem Land zu wohnen, ist entspannend.*

Thanks.

Comment: In English it is not an infinitive but gerund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both examples you give are legit and both are commonly used.

Any German infinitive can be substantized and receive all traits of a substantive. A prominent example might be the translation of Hamlet's *to be or not to be* to

> Sein oder Nichtsein, das ist hier die Frage

or

> Irren ist menschlich

the translation of the Latin "errare humanum est"

Note, in substantive use, the infinitives start with an upper-case letter, and can also carry an article. Note because the infinitive is used as a substantive, there's no additional commas involved - The comma in your first example is wrong.

> [Das] Wohnen auf dem Land ist ...

Your other example uses an *Infinitivsatz* that can act as a subject or object in a sentence. *Infinitivsätze* always use the conjunction "zu" with the infinitive.

> Auf dem Land zu wohnen[,] ist ...

Note this is no substantival use (the whole subclause forms the subject of the sentence) and thus the infinitive starts with a lower case letter. The comma used  to be mandatory, but became optional with the latest changes in German grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are possible, but leave the commas out.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. We’re looking for answers that provide some explanation and context. Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. (This applies to your other recent answers as well.)

Comment: Also, the comma in the second example **can** be used as it is separating an infinitive.